# Trying to post a variable into a jquery click selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, selector

I am trying to insert a variable as a selector on a click event for a dynamic row in a table.  If I hardcode the class name, the row click works fine.  If I change it to the variable it does not.  I have put an alert inside the function to verify that the variable is being passed to the function, and it is.  The row is being dynamically generated into a div tag.

Code that generates the row:

```
$("#testDiv").append('<tr class="PathHideTest"><td></td></tr>');
```

Here is my function:

```
$j(document).ready(function(){    
    var pathName = 'Test';
    $('#testDiv').on('click', 'tr.PathHide' + pathName, function (event {
        alert("Found Row");
    });
});
```

As stated above, if I hard code 'tr.PathHideTest' into the selector, it functions with no problem.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`var pathName='Test'` with uppercase T :)

The code will then be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var pathName = 'Test';
    $('#testDiv').on('click', 'tr.PathHide' + pathName, function (event {
        alert("Found Row");
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part for the sample.  The actual production code has no misspellings in it.  In fact, I can take the value I am building in the variable and paste it directly into the selector and it works beautifully.  I have corrected the original code in the sample.

Comment: Anyone else have any thoughts?

Comment: is the `$J(document)` also a typo?

Comment: It actually is a typo, in our environment jquery is referenced with a $j instead of a $.  I just missed removing this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this.  Here is what I had to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var pathName = '.PathHideTest';
    $('#testDiv').on('click', 'tr' + pathName, function (event {
        alert("Found Row");
     });
});
```

As long as the tr is listed before the variable is appended it works.  Not sure why, but this was the solution.